# Part 2. of developing for Chrome

Tags: php, html, css, browser, google-chrome

I have made the lovely discovery that Jquery corners are not working on Chrome. Any solution for that?

I just figured out that when I turn of my config.js file that holds this (rounded corners functions):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    if(navigator.appName!="Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
      $('.round_10px').corners("10px");
      $('.bottom_round_10px').corners("10px bottom-left 10px bottom-right");
      $('.bottom_l_round_10px').corners("10px bottom-left");
      $('.bottom_r_round_10px').corners("10px bottom-right");
      $('.bottom_top_l_round_10px').corners("10px top-left 10px bottom-left");
      $('.bottom_top_r_round_10px').corners("10px top-right 10px bottom-right");
      $('.round_40px').corners("40px");
    }
```

My site looks how it should...so any known way around this besides turning this off for Chrome all togther?

Comment: Pointing to the exact jquery corners implementation you're using, as well as posting a small bit of sample code that you think should do X, but actually does Y, will get you answers a lot quicker.

Comment: Yea, don't use JavaScript to draw corners for FireFox/Safari/Chrome

Comment: **Off topic tip:** `$(function(){...});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`.

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty sure, that `-webkit-border-radius` most certainly does work on Chrome as it is a webkit-based browser.

I have no way of knowing, which particular plugin you mean, when you say "jQuery corners", but as far as I know, most of them implement rounded corners by using engine-specific styles for FF (`-moz-border-radius`) and webkit (`-webkit-border-radius`) and using borders+trig for IE. That is, assuming, that the task is to make rounded corners without using external resources (images).

Answer (score 3):

Actually the straight CSS3 code: border-radius, works with Chrome too.

Comment: Oh, that's nice to know :) I thought, the actual `border-radius` style was still not standartized.